# C redirect fprintf into a buffer or char array

Tags: c

I have the following function and I am wondering if there is a way to pass `string` or `char` array instead of `stdout` into it so I can get the printed representation as a string.

```
void print_Type(Type t, FILE *f)
{
  fprintf(f,"stuff ...");
}

print_Type(t, stdout);
```

I have already tried this:

```
int SIZE = 100;
char buffer[SIZE];
print_Type(t, buffer);
```

But this is what I am seeing:

```
�����
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
FILE* f = fmemopen(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "w");
print_Type(t, f);
fclose(f);
```

The `fmemopen(void *buf, size_t size, const char *mode)` function opens a stream. The stream allows I/O to be performed on the string or memory buffer pointed to by `buf`.

Comment: How have I been programming in C for almost 40 years and didn't know about this?

Comment: @SteveFriedl non-standard until POSIX 2008?

Comment: 2008 is a long, long time ago and I'm very happy to have learned this.

Comment: Linux manuals also recommend `setbuf(f, NULL);` to make it unbuffered and to make writes fail *as soon* as the buffer is full.

Comment: @SteveFriedl [here's something more for you to learn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64329135/918959)

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is `sprintf()` notice the leading `s` rather than `f`.

```
int SIZE = 100;
char buffer[SIZE];
sprintf(buffer, "stuff %d", 10);
```

This function prints to a string `s` rather than a file `f`. It has exactly the same properties and parameters to `fprintf()` the only difference is the destination, which must be a char array (either statically allocated as an array or dynamical allocated (usually via malloc)).

Note: This function is dangerous as it does not check the length and can easily overrun the end of the buffer if you are not careful.

If you are using a later version of C (c99). A better function is [snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) this adds the extra buffer length checking.

Comment: better use `snprintf` to avoid buffer overflow

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `fmemopen` is that it cannot resize the buffer. `fmemopen` did exist in Glibc for quite some time, but it was standardized only in POSIX.1-2008. But that revision included *another* function that handles dynamic memory allocation: [`open_memstream`(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html):

```
char *buffer = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
FILE* f = open_memstream(&buffer, &size);
print_Type(t, f);
fclose(f);
```

`buffer` will now point to a *null-terminated buffer*, with `size` bytes before the extra null terminator! I.e. you didn't write null bytes, then `strlen(buffer) == size`.

Thus the **only** merit of `fmemopen` is that it can be used to write to a *fixed location memory buffer* or *fixed length*, whereas `open_memstream` should be used everywhere else where the location of the buffer does not matter.

---

For `fmemopen` there is yet another undesired feature - the writes may fail when the buffer is being flushed and not before. Since the target is in memory, there is no point in buffering the writes, so it is suggested that if you choose to use `fmemopen`, [Linux manual page `fmemopen`(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) recommends disabling buffering with `setbuf(f, NULL);`